# GridLayout in NestedScrollView , why do my columns go outside the view space?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Basically when I make a new project in android studio, all default activities contain a NestedScrollView.

If I try to put a grid layout, as its only children, the colums go outside the screen size. You can see that in the picture below:
[image]

this is adding a imagebutton identical to the one with the bottle in (1,1) notice that the width of the button is wrap_content, but there's no content (the wine is an squared icon,set as src,with fitStart scale),yet it covers the whole size of the screen for some reason.

I tried multiple things to make it work, reading stackoverflow I understood that I should use android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout instead of grid layout,and so I did. Then I read that I should add a linear layout as a parent,for some reason,but no fortune.

here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.giuseppi.alessandro.wine.Main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    app:columnCount="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/premium"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        app:layout_row="0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/premium"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

if needed I can provide my whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Check on your Row settings and row sizes.

```
 app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="1" />
```

The rows width is equivalent to the device width. That means any other horizontally placed item goes to the right of the screen.